# Unmount sdcard command android terminal emulator

Tags: android

command on android terminal emulator to unmount the sdcard on my htc wildfire s device?

I have no option in the storage option under settings.

Comment: Not at all possible.. As far as I can remember, there was an app in XDA which had to be installed as a system app, which can unmount memory card. I don't remember its name. And it worked only in some devices..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
adb shell
umount /sdcard
```

With the first command you open a shell with the device, and with the second you unmount the sdcard.

Comment: I dont have adb tools on my computer. I have an ArchLinux OS and I am not well versed with that OS yet, So could you please guide me on the android terminal itself? Or this command works with the android treminal on my phone too?

Comment: Try from the terminal in your phone, it should be the same.

Comment: Okay, I will try that and get back with the results!

Answer (score 0):

before type this:

```
adb root
```

than

```
adb shell
```

for android < 6.x type `fuser -km /data`, maybe need few times, for killing all process related with /data and then you can unmount your 'data'

```
 umount /sdcard
```

Comment: or you can use this command to free sdcard `setprop vold.decrypt trigger_shutdown_framework`

Answer (score 0):

It required super user Access

umount /sdcard

For message: device or resource is busy! 
Restart the device and close the file manager if open, it worked for me